# Mediawiki parse json data on page in php

Tags: php, json, api, mediawiki

I just started using Mediawiki. I'm trying to parse json data from a wiki article in a page.

```
$jsonurl = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvlimit=1&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=Snowy_Owl";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);

var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

I get

> Message:
>   file_get_contents(http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvlimit=1&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=Snowy_Owl)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

I'm not sure why I get this.

Comment: Well, it says "Forbidden". And the MediaWiki API documentation explains why.

Comment: @mario Saying that without pointing to the relevant part of the documentation is not very helpful.

Comment: @svick: It wasn't intended to. First google link. This question shows no research effort. Forgot that yesterday: -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely getting 403, because of [Wikimedia User-Agent policy](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy):

> Scripts should use an informative User-Agent string with contact information

So, you should set the `User-Agent` header to something that will identify your application and that can be used to contact you in case there is some problem.